# javascript object's XMLHttpRequest setRequestHeader method doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with file uploading. I'm using that very method described in [THIS](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/) article. I downloaded the whole script published by the author from [HERE](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/3/filedrag3.zip).
The application is meant to load files through HTML5 drag&drop and then, through javascript, send them to serverside by ajax request.
Everything works fine but the problem occurs when I want to read a parameter from AJAX request header. Here's the code of PHP "file reader":

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);

if ($fn) {
//above there is the upload of the file with file_put_contents function
//which actually works fine when I replace $fn with my own value and ommit the "if" condition
```

Earlier, the XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader method is launched to set "X_FILENAME" header. Here's the javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// start upload
xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
```

And here's the proof (a crop from my Chrome's "firebug"):

[image]

When I *var_dump* the **$fn** variable in PHP it returns boolean FALSE. What is wrong?

P.S. I'm using [XAMPP v1.8.1](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) with Apache 2.4.3 and PHP 5.4.7 on Win7 x64. I'm running the site on the latest Chrome. As you can guess the site is running on localhost. I didn't change anything in php.ini file - everything is set to default.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Underscores don't seem to be valid characters for header names. Use Hyphens and it will work beautifully.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FILENAME", file.name);
```

and no changes are required in your PHP.

Comment: Your solution works great! Thank you. At the first approach I didn't notice the last line in your comment and though I'm doomed.

Answer (score -1):

New versions of Apache and PHP 5.3

```
   $UploadDir=dirname(__FILE__).'/'.;
   $Datos_cabecera=getallheaders();
    $fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
    if (!$fn) {$fn=$Datos_cabecera['X_FILENAME'];} //New versions of Apache and PHP 5.3
    if ($fn) {
    file_put_contents($UploadDir.$fn,file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }
```

Comment: Use variables and comments in english.