# $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] undefined only on Go Daddy

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Hey there so I have sent in a support ticket to go daddy but they aren't being very helpful. In an admin panel for one of my client's websites there is an AJAX image uploader. Normally I don't work with Go Daddy and the script has always worked just fine with other hosts. However this client has forced me into dealing with Go Daddy's mess of a system and I am having trouble getting the AJAX image uploader to work.

The problem seems to be that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']` is simply not defined, even when a file is posted to PHP using an HTTP request.

In my PHP code I have the following line to grab the file name:

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
```

And on Go Daddy it returns false. Also if I `print_r($_SERVER); HTTP_X_FILENAME` isn't even defined.

I have checked permissions and everything has the correct permisssions. I have checked the error log and no error is being generated. I have checked the php.ini and file uploads is enabled with a 32mb max (way bigger than any file i'v tested with)

I have no idea where to look now as my google searches have come up with nothing. (And server admin really isn't my forte)

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks!!

Comment: try $_SERVER['X-Filename'] should work

Comment: Is `$_FILES` inappropriate here?

Comment: I don't know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771777/javascript-objects-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader-method-doesnt-work

Comment: Try this potential solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13852336/283366

Comment: @Satya I'm sure OP would have seen that in `$_SERVER` if it were present. Also, PHP / Apache canonicalise HTTP headers by prefixing with `HTTP` and converting hyphens to underscores

Comment: Are you seeing the `X-Filename` header sent in the request? (check your browser's *Net* developer tab). If so, check the response from the upload request. It should be 200. If it's anything in the 3xx range, then GoDaddy is probably screwing around with rewrites / redirects

Comment: mavrosxristoforos's link solved the problem, thanks all. It looks like it was that I was using "_" instead of "-", odd that it works on some servers but not others.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and mark it as such. You are allowed to do so

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this working. Not sure how you manage saving files on pw when using admin. Do they got saved directly to assets/files/id/ folder or is there tmp somewhere?

```
    // We check if it is image upload
    $filename = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);

    if ($filename) {
        $this->message("It is a file coming!");
        file_put_contents(  
            'C:/Temp/' . $filename,  
            file_get_contents('php://input')  
        );  
    } else {

        if(!$this->isAjaxPost) throw new WireException("This functionality may only be accessed from AJAX POST at present");

                    // etc etc...


}
```

And now I am able to save my files to C:/Temp/. Not sure about the best way to handle this from this situation? Save it to temp folder and use regular pw API and save the file? Or save it right to assets/files/id/ folder and then use API? I can easily send more data (like field name) as a http headers.

If we save it directly to right place (probably safe since this is admin usage), how I get the right path? $config->paths->files->3242 or something like that?